# Using FLTK with Code Blocks...unable to compile?

Tags: c++

I am new to fltk, but I am comfortable using code blocks IDE. I have been trying since last one week to use fltk with code blocks. After unsuccessful attempt to get some help from forum here:

[Unsucessfully trying FLTK with code blocks IDE, getting few errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24007231/unsucessfully-trying-fltk-with-code-blocks-ide-getting-few-errors?noredirect=1#comment37000589_24007231)

I am continuously trying to compile fltk using code blocks with minGW. I came across another tutorial at:

http://complete-concrete-concise.com/programming/fltk/using-fltk-with-codeblocks

followed all the steps, and now I am getting an error as follows:

```
 ld.exe         cannot find –lfltk
```

Guys I am new to this, please help me or guide me some tutorial page….i have tried to google a lot without any success.
Thank you!

Comment: Were there any errors before the link step? Wait a minute this second tutorial assumes that you have fltk built.

Comment: No there are no errors before link step. Yes i also thought of that, but i think somewhere it is going wrong

Comment: After I looked at it this is expected. The tutorial is about building applications assuming you figured out how to build and install FLTK. To me I would not complicate things by using codeblocks ide to build FLTK. I would install a current version of mingw and configure and build FLTK from the command line. After you have FLTK built this tutorial should work.

Comment: Can you please guide how to build FLTK using command line. Please guide me as i have already installed current version of minGW

Comment: http://www.fltk.org/articles.php?L598

Answer (score 0):

take the FL directory and copy contents into C::B include.
then take library files from lib directory and put them into C::B lib direrctory