# Compling FLTK app in linux

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, fltk, fedora-25

I am studying Stroustrup's Principles and Practices using C++. I am trying to get the following program to compile.

```
#include <FL/Fl.H>
#include <FL/Fl_Box.H>
#include <Fl/Fl_Window.H>

int main()
{
    Fl_Window window(200, 200, "Window title");
    Fl_Box box(0,0,200,200,"Hey, I mean, Hello, World!");
    window.show();
    return Fl::run();
}
```

Unfortunately, g++ throws

```
g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp -lfltk -o trial
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/6.3.1/../../../libfltk.so when searching for -lfltk
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /lib/libfltk.so when searching for -lfltk
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/libfltk.so when searching for -lfltk
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lfltk
```

What can I do to solve these errors? I use Fedora 25.

Comment: Do you have the **dev** variant of the FLTK libraries?

Comment: (as it seems to not find the static, linkable libraries)

Comment: Have you installed the *correct* FLTK library? If you run the command `file /usr/lib/libfltk.so` what does it report to you?

Comment: Check this answer if it helps, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24051584/using-fltk-with-code-blocks-unable-to-compile

Comment: Looks like you're picking up the 64 bit version and building a 32-bit version

Answer (score 0):

Installing another version of FLTK-devel solved a problem.